# Pacemaker, corosync delete

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I've got Pacemaker in conjunction with Corosync on two nodes and two float ip.
Now I need to delete this construction.

What is the best way to stop Pacemaker and Corosync and delete them?

Comment: you need to specify if you are using pcs or crm shell and your distribution.

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question!)

pcs is used

Answer (score 1):

For more information about pcs you can follow the Redhat documentation, anyway, you can use the following to achieve your task:

```
pcs resource show
pcs resource delete resource_id
```

After you deleted all your defined resources, Now you can disable and stop the cluster with:

```
pcs cluster disable --all
pcs cluster stop --all
```

Comment: After that may I stop and delete like this: #systemctl stop pacemaker #systemctl stop corosync ; and #yum remove pacemaker corosync ?

Comment: @alex use pcs cluster disable --all and pcs cluster stop --all as suggested in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my next step will be installing keepalived, so is it correct to stop and remove pacemaker and corosync after #pcs cluster disable --all and #pcs cluster stop --all?

Comment: @alex could I ask you why do you need to disable the cluster and install keepalived?

Comment: Cause keepalived is easier to use and all in our command know how do this, but nobody knows pcs.

Comment: @alex keepalived is not real cluster solution, easier can become fatal, anyway, all pcs commands are in redhat documentation